# Reading a reg key that contains a CRLF?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, special-characters, newlines

If a registry key, exports to a reg file as:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\key
]
"test"="1"
```

and from a PS window, the following works:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\key
"
```

but the following fails:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\key"
```

How might you reference this key with Reg.exe?

In Notepad++ it appears as CRLF.

EDITS:

1. Thanks for the comment. It wasn't created by me but I'm trying to read it which then made me pretty curious. I see you can create a key with PS, using the ISE as an example where the value of the name is split over 2 lines:

   ```
   new-item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\a\" -name "test

   "
   ```

Comment: if the key really contains a new line then just `Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\key\`n"` is enough. But how did you create that key? `New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\key\`n"` doesn't work

Comment: technically that name is invalid because only printable characters except backslash \ are allowed in keynames and new line is not a printable character [What are the valid characters for Registry keys and valuenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013473). So it's probably a bug in the registry which doesn't validate names correctly